# How to dynamically create and pass an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add and invoke function dynamically. For that, below is the code

```js
filed = [];

function fileIt(thing) {
    // Dynamically call the file method of whatever
    thing.addIt();

    // Mark as filed
    filed.push(thing);
}

function repType1(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

repType1.prototype.addIt = function () {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log("Heloo From repType1");
}

function repType2(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

repType2.prototype.addIt = function () {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log("Heloo From repType2");
}

let rep1 = new repType1("repType1");
fileIt(rep1);
```

I am able to call function using `let rep1 = new repType1("repType1");` for `repType1`but i need to do it dynamically so that same line of code can call my other function 'repType2' as well. I have the function parameter value as string for example: "repType1", "repType2", etc. How to do it?

Comment: So you want to attach `addIt` dynamically to given objects? or what?

Comment: @Adriani6 Yes, i want to call `repType1` or `repType2` by dynamically creating object not by statically typing like `let rep1 = new repType1("repType1");`. Just want to pass the value that comes from string and accordingly invoke `addIt` either from `repType1` or `repType2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you are trying to mutate objects to perform something like the following If I understood you correctly :

```js
const filed = [];

function fileIt(thing) {
  // Dynamically call the file method of whatever
  thing.addIt();

  // Mark as filed
  filed.push(thing);
}

class RepType {
   addItrepType1() {
     //Business Logic will go here
     console.log('Heloo From repType1');
   }
   
   addItrepType2() {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log('Heloo From repType2');
   }
   
   constructor(type) {
      // Set the function depending on the type
      this.addIt = this[`addIt${type}`];
      
      this.name = name;
   }
}

const rep1 = new RepType('repType1');
const rep2 = new RepType('repType2');

fileIt(rep1);
fileIt(rep2);
```

---

Though I would recommand you to use the inheritance system like :

```js
const filed = [];

function fileIt(thing) {
  // Dynamically call the file method of whatever
  thing.addIt();

  // Mark as filed
  filed.push(thing);
}

// Abstract class
class ARepType {
  addIt() {
    throw new Error('Unimplemented abstract method');
  }

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Abstract';
  }
}

class RepType1 extends ARepType {
  // override the function
  addIt() {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log('Heloo From repType1');
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.name = 'repType1';
  }
}

class RepType2 extends ARepType {
  // override the function
  addIt() {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log('Heloo From repType2');
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.name = 'repType2';
  }
}

const rep1 = new RepType1();
const rep2 = new RepType2();

fileIt(rep1);
fileIt(rep2);
```

Comment: Great approaches

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way!

```js
filed = [];

function fileIt(thing) {
    // Dynamically call the file method of whatever
    thing.addIt();

    // Mark as filed
    filed.push(thing);
}

function RepType() {
    RepType.types = {repType1, repType2};
    this.addIt = function () {
    };

    RepType.of = function (type) {
        return new (this.types[type])();
    };
}


function repType1(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

repType1.prototype = new RepType();
repType1.prototype.addIt = function () {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log("Heloo From repType1");
};

function repType2(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

repType2.prototype = new RepType();
repType2.prototype.addIt = function () {
    //Business Logic will go here
    console.log("Heloo From repType2");
};

let rep1 = RepType.of("repType1");

fileIt(rep1);
```

Comment: @Lara, then you have to store the function references. updated above